# Java's RSA/ECB/OAEPWITHSHA-256ANDMGF1PADDING equivalent in PHP

Tags: java, php, encryption, rsa, phpseclib

I have a case where a 'secret' is coming to me from a Java App and it's cipher'd using a public key and the RSA/ECB/OAEPWITHSHA-256ANDMGF1PADDING cipher. I'm trying to decipher it at my end, but I'm not sure how to get the equivalent of that cipher. I've been using phpseclib for other security stuff, and I've tried the OAEP encryption mode in there, but to no avail. I just get a decrypt error with no information. I just want to state that the keys are correct:

```
function oaes_decrypt($ciphertext, $privatekey) {
    $rsa = new \Crypt_RSA();
    $rsa->setEncryptionMode(CRYPT_RSA_ENCRYPTION_OAEP);
    $rsa->setMGFHash('sha256');
    $rsa->setHash('sha256');
    $rsa->loadKey($privatekey);

    return $rsa->decrypt($ciphertext);
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-private-decrypt.php This seems like the most likely candidate, although `OPENSSL_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING` doesn't seem that specific. I don't know if you can do it this way; have you considered using libsodium instead? `crypto_box_seal()` and `crypto_box_seal_open()` would work for this use case.

Comment: Thanks Scott. I'll try PHP's open ssl method with  OPENSSL_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING and see if it does the trick. Failing that, I'll have a look at https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium-php.

Comment: openssl_private_decrypt() did not work. Will let you know how I get on with libsodium.

Comment: Sadly, I'm going to have to do this on Windows. Anyone knows how to get libsodium working on windows, without Vsual Studio?

Comment: http://doc.libsodium.org/bindings_for_other_languages/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `$rsa->setMGFHash('sha1');` The `SHA-256` in `RSA/ECB/OAEPWITHSHA-256ANDMGF1PADDING` doesn't refer to the MGF1 hash. To have that be sha256 you'd have to be doing this:

```
Cipher oaepFromInit = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPPadding");
OAEPParameterSpec oaepParams = new OAEPParameterSpec("SHA-256", "MGF1", new MGF1ParameterSpec("SHA-1"), PSpecified.DEFAULT);
oaepFromInit.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privkey, oaepParams);
byte[] pt = oaepFromInit.doFinal(ct);
System.out.println(new String(pt, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

The final result, that works, in PHP:

```
function oaes_decrypt($ciphertext, $privatekey) {
    $rsa = new \Crypt_RSA();
    $rsa->setEncryptionMode(CRYPT_RSA_ENCRYPTION_OAEP);
    $rsa->setMGFHash('sha1');
    $rsa->setHash('sha256');
    $rsa->loadKey($privatekey);

    return $rsa->decrypt($ciphertext);
}
```

Comment: Yup that is what I tried earlier this morning (on advice from someone else, and it worked). I'll add to your answer and then accept it. Thanks.